# Choosing a complementary Lie subalgebra well

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have a compact connected Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and a codimension one closed subgroup $H$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$. Using an inner product on $\mathfrak{g}$ one can then choose some complementary Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{k}$ and exponeniate that to get a Lie subgroup $K$. Now, as there are a lot of inner products, there is presumably a lot of ways to choose a complementary Lie subalgebra. However, there are clearly some choices that are better than others e.g. I would like to choose $\mathfrak{k}$ so that $\exp(t\mathfrak{k})$ is closed and so the associated Lie group is isomorphic to $S^1$. Then I would like to choose it so that it's the most "basic" $S^1$ possible, which I guess is asking that it represents a generator of $H_1(G)$... Is there a way to choose the inner product so that one chooses the "correct" complementary Lie algebra?

Comment: I understand "I would like to choose $\mathfrak{k}$ so that $\exp(t\mathfrak{k})$ is closed and so the associated Lie group is isomorphic to $S^1$" but not "I would like to choose it so that it's the most "basic" $S^1$ possible, which I guess is asking that it represents a generator of $H_1(G)$"

Comment: It won't generate $H_1(G)$ unless $H_1(G)$ is rank 1.

Comment: A remark is that $H$ is necessarily normal and contains $[G,G]$. If $Z$ is the connected center of $G$, we have $G=HZ$, and the question boils down to the same question within $Z$ and its codimension-1 subgroup $H\cap Z$, i.e., boils down to the abelian case. Also note that because of this remark, if the conjugacy-invariant scalar product is chosen to be rational on $Z$ i.e., take rational values on the kernel of the exponential map $\mathfrak{z}\to G$), then the exponential of the orthogonal is automatically closed.

Comment: You don't need an inner product to construct a complementary one-dimensional subspace $\frak k$ to a Lie suabalgebra $\frak h$  of $\frak g$ of codimension 1. You just choose any one-dimensional subspace $\frak k$ not contained in $\frak h$. However, as you write, some choices are better than others.

Comment: As @YCor has noticed, $\frak h$ contains $[\frak g,\frak g]$. It would be wise to choose $\frak k$ inside the center $\frak z(\frak g)$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi if one chooses a bi-invariant scalar product, the orthogonal is automatically in the center (since the bi-invariant scalar product can be chosen arbitrarily on the center, each complement can be obtained this way, and each complement generating a closed 1-parameter subgroup can be obtain this way when requiring the scalar product to be rational on the kernel of $\exp:\mathfrak{z}\to G$).

Comment: Again, as @YCor has noticed, the question  reduces to the case when $G$ is a compact torus and $H$ is a subtorus of codimension one. Let ${\frak g}_{\Bbb Z}$ denote the kernel of the exponential map $\exp\colon {\frak g}\to G$. We obtain a $\Bbb Z$-stucture in $\frak  g$. The $\Bbb R$-subspace $\frak h$ is defined over $\Bbb Q$.  The one-dimensional subspace $\frak k$ corresponds to a subtorus of $\frak g$ if and only if it defined over $\Bbb  Q$, that is, generated by some vector in ${\frak g}_{\Bbb Z}$ not contained in $\frak h$.

Comment: Again, some choices of this one-dimensional subspace $\frak k$ are better than others. Consider the quotient group $A={\frak g}_{\Bbb Z}/{\frak h}_{\Bbb Z}$. It is easy to see that $A$ is a free abelian group of rank 1. Consider the group ${\frak k}_{\Bbb Z}:={\frak k}\cap {\frak g}_{\Bbb Z}$. Again it is a free abelian group of rank 1. The canonical projection $\pi\colon {\frak g}\to {\frak g}/{\frak h}$ induces a homomorphism $\pi_*\colon {\frak k}_{\Bbb Z}\to A$. For a better choice, you may choose $\frak k$ such  the homomorphism $\pi_*$ is surjective.

Comment: In other words, you choose a generator $a$ of $A$ and a pre-image $x\in {\frak g}_{\Bbb Z}$ of $a$ under $\pi_*$. Then you take for $\frak k$ the $\Bbb R$-subspace of $\frak g$ generated by $x$.

Comment: We can identify $H_1(G, \Bbb Z) $ with ${\frak g}_{\Bbb Z}$, the image of  $H_1(H,\Bbb Z)$ with ${\frak h}_{\Bbb Z}$,  and the image of $H_1(K,\Bbb Z)$ with ${\frak k}_{\Bbb Z}$, where $K$ is our new  one-dimensional subtorus with Lie algebra $\frak k$. With the above choice we have $$ H_1(G,\Bbb Z)=H_1(H,\Bbb Z)\oplus H_1(K,\Bbb Z).$$

Comment: @YCor: I agree with you, but I personally find it easier to choose a  vector in $\frak z(\frak g)$ not contained in $\frak h$ than to construct an invariant scalar product on $\frak g$ and then to compute the orthogonal complement to $\frak h$ ....

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi yes you're right: one just needs a rational supplement within the centre.